# How to display information in a string?

Tags: angular

I need to display the column name from json. But the problem is that all column names are displayed in 1 column. And for some reason empty fields are added. And how it is possible to deduce in a line of a name of columns?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead >
    <tr *ngFor="let attribute of attributes" >
      <ng-container *ngIf="(attribute.is_visible) == true">
        <th style="text-align: center;" ><b>{{attribute.name }}</b></th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 ...
```

Comment: Can you show your json and required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this =>

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr> 
     <th *ngFor="let attribute of attributes" style="text-align: center;" >
     <ng-container *ngIf="(attribute.is_visible) == true">
     <b>{{attribute.name }}</b>
     </ng-container>
     </th>  
  </tr>
```

In your case you are looping through in `<tr>` which causes to build a new row for every iteration. instead do it inside `<th>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let attribute of attributes">
        <th *ngIf="(attribute.is_visible) == true" style="text-align: center;" ><b>{{attribute.name }}</b></th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
 </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution

use `*ngFor` in `th` tag.

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-display-information-in-a-string?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let attribute of attributes" style="text-align: center;">
                <ng-container *ngIf="(attribute.is_visible) == true">
                    <b>{{attribute.name }}</b>
                </ng-container>
            </th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```